# How to pass parameters between functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop, parameters

I am currently having to build a program that converts numerical grades into letter grades and
uses 2 functions, a `main()` and `grade()`. I have to calculate and send the grade to the main function.
From the `main()` function I have to print tables and a while loop that print the grades starting at 101 with invalid score, decreasing grades by 7.5 until below 50, and then 1 final -1 invalid score. This is what I have so far but still not getting how to properly send data through a function.

```
def main():    
    print("score\tletter grade")
    print("-----\t------------")

    letter_grade = grade(101)

    while letter_grade < 50:
        print(num_grade,'\t', letter_grade)
        letter_grade -= 7.5

def grade(num_grade):
    A = 89.5
    B = 79.5
    C = 69.5
    D = 59.5
    F = 0

    if num_grade >= 100.1:
        print("Invalid Score")

    elif num_grade >= A:
        print("A")

    elif num_grade >= B:
        print("B")

    elif num_grade >= C:
        print("C")

    elif num_grade >= D:
        print("D")

    elif num_grade >= F:
        print("F")
    else:
        print("Invalid Score")
    return num_grade

main()
```

Comment: Please clearly define your problem. What do you mean by "properly send data through a function"?

Comment: Show the output you want and the output you get as properly formatted text in the question (shortened to relevant parts if necessary).

Comment: MisterMiyagi I need to send the converted grade from the grade(num_grade) function to the while loop inside the main() function. and print a table of both the numbered grade and converted letter grade

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You posted a large amount of code for a four-line problem that you haven't specified.  You dumped your entire assignment specification and program, and then say that you don't understand one aspect that is covered well in tutorials on functions.  Please be *specific*, and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `return` statement.

In the `grade()` function, instead of printing the result (which you do in the main) you sort of send it back with the return statement, it's through this statement that a function can comunicate the value computed.

So in your case I would rewrite grade as follow:

```
def grade():
# ....
   if num_grade >= 100.1:
        return "Invalid score"

    elif num_grade >= A:
        return "A"

    elif num_grade >= B:
        return "B"

    elif num_grade >= C:
        return "C"

    elif num_grade >= D:
        return "D"

    elif num_grade >= F:
        return "F"
    else:
        return "Invalid score"
```

The value returned by a function is then assigned to the variable through: `letter_grade = grade(101)`.

There is another error in the while loop since num_grade I think it's not declared.
You can do:

```
def main():
      num_grade = 101
      while num_grade > 50: # <- pay attention here
      # I want to update the letter grade at each cycle
      # with the diminished num_grade
      letter_grade = grade(num_grade)
      print(num_grade,'\t', letter_grade)
      # now decrement the num grade
      num_grade -= 7.5
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, gives me a better view of how they send and receive data.